# Отправка одноразового сообщения с inline-keyboard при команде старт бота на python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Я бы хотел чтобы мой бот отправлял одноразовое сообщения с `inline-keyboard`  при ***первом*** нажатии команды `/start`. (если будут нажимать повторно команду старт или перезапускать бота то что бы сообщения  каждый раз не выбивало. Только при первом нажатии команды старт)

При нажатии inline-клавиши  "согласится" под сообщениям тебя перебрасывало в основное меню.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Хотите - делайте, или говорите точнее что у вас не получается...

Comment: Ну так просто запиши в бд факт нажатия, а после проверяй в хендлере

Comment: Можете пожалуста написать кодом